# Como parametrizar uma rota no Vue?

Tags: vue.js, link, router

Estou usando o `vue/router` para fazer um spa, e estou com dificuldade de enviar o id de um determinado produto pela url...
estou fazendo assim no link:

```
 <router-link :to="{name:'editar',params:{id:item.id}}">editar2</router-link>
```

## rota:

```
 const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: Vue.component('home-page')
}, {
    path: '/teste',
    component: Vue.component('home-page')
}, {
    path: '/editar',
    'name': editar,
    component: Vue.component('home-page')
}]
const myRouter = new VueRouter({
    routes
})
```

mas não funciona de jeito nenhum...como faço esse cara mandar o id pela `url`?

Comment: Como você configurou sua rota?

Comment: o arquivo de rotas está configurado assim:


    const routes=[
        { path:'/', component: Vue.component('home-page') },
        { path:'/teste', component: Vue.component('home-page') },
        { path:'/editar','name':editar, component: Vue.component('home-page') }
    ]
    const myRouter = new VueRouter({routes})

Comment: tente:  `{
    path: '/editar:id',
    'name': editar,
    component: Vue.component('home-page')
}`

Comment: então, o problema é o link...ele não envia parametros

Comment: `<router-link to='`/editar/${id:item.id}`'>editar2</router-link>`

Comment: não foi ainda...deu erro por causa do $ (não estou trabalhando com o node.js é uma aplicação simples) removendo o $ também, não funcionou

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81240/discussion-between-horacio-neto-and-marconi).

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa especificar o nome do parâmetro na declaração da rota:

```
{
    path: '/editar/:id',
    name: 'editar',
    component: Vue.component('home-page')
}
```

E para obter o parametro recebido

`$route.params.id` ou `this.$route.params.id`

Para mais informações leia a [documentação do vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html).